# What am I doing wrong in declaring an array of objects in php?

Tags: php

This might be something too obvious, but I am kind of brain dead at the moment.

```
$sizeArr = array({
                    "name"=>'18"x24"',"wd"=>18,"ht"=>24,"price"=>99.00
                },
                {
                    "name"=>'24"x36"',"wd"=>24,"ht"=>36,"price"=>189.00
                });
```

i want it to be accessed like `$sizeArr[0]->name`, but I am getting an error saying `Unexpected {`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using anonymous object syntax, familiar in other languages, that doesn't exist in PHP. You cannot `$o = { 'foo => 'bar' };`. However, can create an instance of `stdClass`, like so: `$o = new stdClass; $o->foo = 'bar';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `{}` to define objects in PHP like you would in JavaScript (which I'm assuming you're familiar with).

In PHP objects and arrays are both `array`s - yes, this does give problems if you're serialising to JSON.

So:

```
$sizeArr = array(array(
    "name"=>'18"x24"',"wd"=>18,"ht"=>24,"price"=>99.00
),
array(
    "name"=>'24"x36"',"wd"=>24,"ht"=>36,"price"=>189.00
));
```

Comment: Objects are not arrays. They use different fields in the struct used to store zend values in the internals. What you really mean, I think, is "in PHP dictionaries and arrays are both arrays".

Comment: @Denis maybe so, but there is (to my knowledge) no way to leverage that difference in PHP itself. indexed-arrays and associative-arrays are indistinguishable (which can be a problem). I used the terminology OP used, `object` is very loosely defined, especially when talking about two languages at once.

Comment: While objects are definitely *not* arrays, this is still a better approach. You have to define it as an array before you'd be able to make it an object (via casting), so it makes sense to just leave it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your array:

```
$yourArray = array (
   'item1' => 'Apple',
   'item2' => 'Peach'
);

$p = (object) $yourArray;
print $p->item1;
```

For multidimensional Arrays, have a look here: http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `{}` for this but you can try this

`(object)` is for convert `array` to `object`

```
 $sizeArr = array(
     (object)array(
       "name"=>'18"x24"',"wd"=>18,"ht"=>24,"price"=>99.00
     ),
     (object)array(
      "name"=>'24"x36"',"wd"=>24,"ht"=>36,"price"=>189.00
     )
 );
 echo $sizeArr[0]->name;
```

`$sizeArr` structure  `print_r($sizeArr);` output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 18"x24"
        [wd] => 18
        [ht] => 24
        [price] => 99
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => 24"x36"
        [wd] => 24
        [ht] => 36
        [price] => 189
    )

)
```

output:

```
18"x24"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sizeArr = array(
                    (object)array("name"=>'18"x24"',"wd"=>18,"ht"=>24,"price"=>99.00),
                    (object)array("name"=>'24"x36"',"wd"=>24,"ht"=>36,"price"=>189.00)
                    );



    $sizeArr[0]->name;
```

Comment: You can't convert the array of arrays to an object because it has no [valid] keys that could be assigned. You have to convert each array inside the array to an object one by one (via a loop most likely) to make an array of objects.